# How to make deployment of PHP files with Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have Android Studio project, where I store (in separate folder) PHP files (implementing web services). The whole project is built and maintained by Gradle plugin to Studio.

How to make Gradle to deploy (copy) these files from project to external Apache \htdocs localisation? Is it possible to copy theses files during Gradle build process? if so, how to copy them only if there are differences between files in project folder and files in external \htdocs localisation.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Apache server runs on the same machine, you can create a [Gradle copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files) to copy single files or whole directories to a specific location:

```
task copyWebFiles(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/web'             // source directory
    into '../path/to/htdocs'   // target directory
}

preBuild.dependsOn copyWebFiles  // execute task before build
```

As part of your app's *build.gradle* file.

Comment: I was looking into this documentation but I have omitted this fragment about copy task. Great thanks.